# RACCommand separate handling of successful completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a problem with implementing some logical simply code.
In simple terms I want to make something like this:

```
Complete command() {
    if (error) {
        show error alert
    }
    else {
        show "Happy ending" allert
    }
}
```

I know how to make first part, but with second I have a problem

My try:

```
[self.vm.applyCommand.errors subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    //Show alert with error
}];

[[[self.vm.applyCommand.executionSignals
    map:^(RACSignal *signal) {
        return [[signal ignoreValues] materialize];
    }]
    concat]
    subscribeNext:^(RACEvent *event) {
        //Show alert with "Happy end"
    }];
```

In this case everything works as expected until error appears. In case of error I see **two alerts** (one with error, another with "Happy end"), but want only one with error.

I know why it happens,

> Errors will be automatically caught upon the inner signals ...etc

but I want some solution to make desirable behavior.

UPD: "...see **two alerts** (one with error, another with "Happy end")"

Comment: The way you handle errors seems to be correct. There is something wrong with either showing the error alerts (in `subscribeNext` block) or in the execution signal of `applyCommand`. Could you show us the relevant code?

Comment: "My try:" is relevant code

Comment: I meant the part "//Show alert with error" and the implementation of execution signal of `self.vm.applyCommand` (the one which is passed to `initWithSignalBlock`).

Comment: It dosen't matter what happened in initWithSignalBlock. It is in viewModel. The problem above happens in view.

Comment: It can affect the view, because it can (for example) send the error twice to the subscriber. What I'm saying is that we can't deduce what's wrong only basing on this code: `[self.vm.applyCommand.errors subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    //Show alert with error
}];`. RACCommand is tested and it surely doesn't send the same error twice in `errors` signal. If it does, report an issue on their GitHub repo. The problem must be somewhere else, in the code we don't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways to achieve what you want, depending on how the execution signal for `applyCommand` behaves.

If it sends only one `next` value and then immediately completes, you can simply use `switchToLatest` operator to subscribe for that `next` value and display the alert with 'Happy end':

```
  [[self.command.executionSignals switchToLatest] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    //Show alert with "Happy end"
  }];
```

Otherwise it's much more complicated, because it's hard to distinguish between successful completion and failure of `RACCommand`'s execution signal. In case of error you get a "completed" `RACEvent` when calling `[[signal ignoreValues] materialize];`, and then command's `errors` signal sends the error as its next value.

I managed to do it using command's `executing` signal, which sends `@NO` *after* the `errors` signal sends the error. You can use `merge` and `combinePreviousWithStart:reduce` operators to check if the command stopped executing because an error occurred:

```
RACSignal *stoppedExecuting = [[self.vm.applyCommand.executing ignore:@YES] skip:1];
RACSignal *merged = [stoppedExecuting merge:self.vm.applyCommand.errors];

[[[merged combinePreviousWithStart:nil reduce:^id(id previous, id current) {
  return @( [previous isKindOfClass:[NSError class]] || [current isKindOfClass:[NSError class]] );
}] filter:^BOOL(NSNumber *errorOccurred) {
  return !errorOccurred.boolValue;
}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
  NSLog(@"Happy end!");
}];
```

It's not a perfect solution as it depends on order of sending values from various `RACCommand`'s signals, which is an implementation detail and can change in the future (it worked for me with RAC 2.5). 
I suppose that this problem might be solved with RAC 3.0, as it [replaces `RACCommand` with `Action`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/v3.0-RC.1/CHANGELOG.md#commands-are-now-actions), but I haven't tried it yet.